# Tagging files in Teams

Tags: properties, tags

This might be overly simple for this forum, but let's try:
I have a bunch of files in Teams, and I want to tag them with a radio button - either "Red Review Ready" or "Return to Owner". I have created the column and it's telling me I need to add info:

[image]

My question is - how the frick do I actually add the tag? I click the ellipses > Details and select a value and Teams tells me it's saving that value:

[image]

But when I go back to the main screen, that tag is not applied. Please help before I attempt to teach my laptop how to fly.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

NVM it seems to have caught up with itself.
Bloody Teams